# Is there a rule of thumb for how granular an object should be in OO programming?

Tags: class, oop

I'm in school learning OO programming, and for the next few months, every assignment involves dice games and word games like jumble and hangman. Each assignment has us creating a new class for these variables; HangmanWordArray, JumbleWordArray, etc. In the interest of reusability, I want to create a class (or series of classes) that can be re-used for my assignments. I'm having a hard time visualizing what that would look like, and hope my question makes sense...

Let's assume that the class(es) will contain properties with accessors and mutators, and methods to return the various objects...a word, a letter, a die roll. Is there a rule of thumb for how to organize these classes?

Is it best to keep one object per class? Or group all the objects in a single class because they're all related as "stuff I need for assignments?" Or group by data type, so all the numeric objects are in one class and all the strings in another?

I guess I'm grappling with how a programmer, in the real world, makes decisions about how to group objects within a class or series of classes, and some of the questions and thought processes I should be using to frame this type of design scenario.

Comment: The answer is "no" -- there is no rule of thumb.  Knowing how to break things up comes with experience.  After 5-10 years you begin to get it right.

Comment: (And forget about "reusability" -- it's a fiction.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OOP not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realistically, it varies from project to project. There is no guaranteed 'right way' to group anything; it all depends on your needs. What it comes down to is manageability, meaning how easily you can read and update old code. If you can contain all your games in a single 'games' class, then there's nothing wrong with doing it. However, if your games are very complicated with many subs and variables, perhaps moving them all to their own class would be easier to manage.

That being said, there are ways to logically group items. For instance if you have a lot of solo functions that are used for manipulation (char to string, string to int, html encode/decode, etc.), you may decide to create a 'helper functions' class to hold them all. Similarly, if your application uses a database connection, you may create a class to hold and manage a shared connection as well as have methods for getting query results and executing non-queries.

Some people try to break things down to much. For example, instead of having the database core mentioned above, they might create one class to create and manage the database connection. They will create another class to then use the connection class to handle queries. Not that this method won't work, but it may become very difficult to manage when items are split up too small.

Without knowing exactly what you are doing, there's no way to tell you how to do it. If you reuse the same methods in each project, then perhaps you can place them somewhere that they can be shared. The best way I found to figuring out what works best is just to try it out and see how it responds!

Comment: "The best way I found to figuring out what works best is just to try it out and see how it responds!" -- Very true!

Answer (score 2):

What I see people doing is breaking down their objects and methods until each method is just a handful of code;  if any method exceeds a page of code, they will try to break down the object structure further in order to shorten things up.

I personally have no objection to long methods, as long as they are readable.  I think a "one-page limit" tends to create too much granularity, and risks more confusion rather than less.  But this seems to be the current fashion.

Just reporting what I'm seeing in the wild.

Comment: And as an old COBOL hack used to an inch-high stack of fanfold on his desk, I'm a BIG fan of long classes and methods...much to my detriment in grasping OO architecture and design. :)

Comment: Well, you could use the "one-page limit" on methods as a rule of thumb until you get the hang of it.  Once you get used to breaking down object structures, you can always back off a little.  I used to over-normalize databases (normalization is good!) until I figured out that there is a point where one more dimension table just makes everything harder, and there's no need.  But it's good practise.

Comment: I've actually been trying to limit myself to one panel in Visual Studio so I can just flip between tabs instead of flip & scroll. That's been fairly successful so far. When I decide to stick to it. :)

Comment: There used to be an advantage to the one-page rule, back when you used printouts and a page was a page.  But a modern video screen is just too small to contain many methods, and, as you suggest, breaking things down arbitrarily obfuscates rather than illuminates.